# Layout with CSS does not align properly

Tags: css

Here is what my final layout should look like:

Unfotunately I am having trouble getting the two columns to layout properly with my css coding. When I use the float: left; coding it stacks them on top of each other.

```css
    /*------ Document -----*/
    body {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     font: .75em/1.5em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     color: #797267;
     width: 960px;
     background: #797267;
    }
    
    /**--- Headers ---*/
    
    header {
     width: 960px;
     height: 210px;
     background-image: url(../images/header-bg.jpg);
    }
    
    h1 {
     width: 317px;
     height: 71px;
     padding: 64px 0px 0px 64px;
     margin: 64px 64px 0px 0px;
     
    }
    
    h2 {
     color: #423b2e;
     size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    /*--- Navigation ---*/
    
    nav {
     color: #423b2e;
    }
    
    #current {
     color: #bf3102;
    }
    
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 84px 64px 0px 0px;
        float: right;
        clear: left;
        width: 277px;
    } 
    
    li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    /*--- Banner --*/
    
    div {
     background-image: url(../images/main-content-bg.jpg);
     width: 960px;
    }
    
    div #banner {
     background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
     width: 890px;
     height: 200px;
     margin: auto;
     background-repeat: none;
    }
    
    /*--- Two-Columns Content --*/
    
    
    #column1of2 {
     width: 450px;
     padding: 25px;
    }
    
    #column1of2.page-flip {
     background-image: url(../images/page-flip.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: left bottom;
     width: 450px;
     margin: 0px 0px 45px 64px;
    }
    
    #column2of2 {
     width: 260px;
     padding: 25px;
    }
    
    #column2of2.page-flip {
     background-image: url(../images/page-flip.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: left bottom;
     width: 260px;
     margin: 0px 0px 45px 44px;
    }
    
    
    /*--- Footer --*/
    
    footer {
     background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     color: #423b2e;
     size: .9em;
     text-align: center;
     width: 960px;
     padding: 92px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>BusinessName</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
     </head>
     <body>  
      <header>
      
       <h1><a href="index.html">BusinessName</a></h1>
      
       <nav>
      
        <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html" id="current">Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      
       </nav>
      
      </header>
     
      <div id="main-content">  
      
       <div id="banner">
    
       </div>
     
          <section id="column1of2" class="page-flip">
      
              <h2>Who We Are (h2)</h2>
     
               <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
               
              <p>Aenean pretium tellus  sit amet enim. Donec laoreet urna ut pede. Nulla eget magna at felis feugiat imperdiet.</p>
              
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       
          </section>
          
          <section id="column2of2" class="page-flip">
       
              <h2>How We Can Help (h2)</h2>
              
              <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb1.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>
     
          <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb2.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>
    
              <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb3.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>
    
          </section>
          
      </div>
      
      <footer>
      
       <p>&copy; BusinessName. All rights reserved. </p>
      
      </footer> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake. `float: left;` is not applied to either of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, did you try to use Display:inline?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.I don't have your images.so i set the beckground-color for demo.

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font: .75em/1.5em Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #797267;
    width: 960px;
    background: #797267;
}

/**--- Headers ---*/

header  {
    width: 960px;
    height: 210px;
    background-image: url(../images/header-bg.jpg);
    background-color:red;
}

h1  {
    width: 317px;
    height: 71px;
    padding: 64px 0px 0px 64px;
    margin: 64px 64px 0px 0px;

}

h2  {
    color: #423b2e;
    size: 1.5em;
}

/*--- Navigation ---*/

nav {
    color: #423b2e;
}

#current    {
    color: #bf3102;
}



ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 84px 64px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    width: 277px;
} 

li {
    display: inline;
}

/*--- Banner --*/

div {
    background-image: url(../images/main-content-bg.jpg);
    width: 960px;
    background-color:black;
}

div #banner {
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    width: 890px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-color:green;
}

/*--- Two-Columns Content --*/


#column1of2 {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 25px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#column1of2.page-flip {
    background-image: url(../images/page-flip.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0px 0px 45px 64px;
}

#column2of2 {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}

#column2of2.page-flip {
    background-image: url(../images/page-flip.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 0px 0px 45px 44px;
}


/*--- Footer --*/

footer  {
    background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #423b2e;
    size: .9em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 92px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color:green;
   clear:both;
  
}
```

```html
<header>

            <h1><a href="index.html">BusinessName</a></h1>

            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" id="current">Home</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>

        </header>

        <div id="main-content">     

            <div id="banner">

            </div>

            <section id="column1of2" class="page-flip">

                <h2>Who We Are (h2)</h2>

                 <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <p>Aenean pretium tellus  sit amet enim. Donec laoreet urna ut pede. Nulla eget magna at felis feugiat imperdiet.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            </section>

            <section id="column2of2" class="page-flip">

                <h2>How We Can Help (h2)</h2>

                <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb1.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>

                <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb2.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>

                <p><img width="70" height="70" alt="placeholder image" src="images/sample-thumb3.jpg" /> Sunc auctor, est a scelerisque vehicula, tortor nulla imperdiet elit, eu tincidunt ligula. </p>

            </section>

        </div>

        <footer>

            <p>&copy; BusinessName. All rights reserved. </p>

        </footer>
```